# Using a single button for Save and edit functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, controller-extension

In my VF page I show both save and edit button. I would like to use only one button for both edit and save. The button label should switch between save and edit depending upon the situation. That means when I am editing the page the button should show "save" and when I the VF page is saved it should show button as "edit". How can I do that?

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" extensions="SkillReviewExtension" showHeader="false">

  <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Candidate Skill Evaluation" id="skills_list">

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>



      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >

       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Level">

        <apex:selectList value="{!Level1}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:outputText value="{!Level1}"/>       
</apex:column>

       <apex:column headerValue="Description"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Comments">
       <apex:inputTextarea value="{!inputValue}" id="theTextInput" rendered="{!isEditMode}"/>
       <apex:outputText value="{!inputValue}" />
        </apex:column>

       </apex:pageBlockTable>


 </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: No , this is about changing the button label dynamically based on operation

Comment: @AdrianLarson Looks copy and pasted from that to me.

Comment: It is the same VF page but I the requirement is different. I would like to keep a single button for both edit and save instead of two separate buttons. Thanks

Comment: and why can't you use a merge field for the `value=` attribute value `{!actionBtnLabel}` that is set by your controller ?

Comment: Why not add `rendered="{!isEditMode}"` to your save button and `rendered="{!!isEditMode}"` to your edit button?